# php dopdown filter is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

This is product filter page. I want to filter data by drop down. by php and mysqli database. I fetch data from database and put in dropdown. But it is not filtering after selecting value. trying from long time. did all possible way. please help me out in this code thank you.

```js
var colour,brand,size,achievements ;
 $(function(){
  $('.item_filter').click(function(){
   $('.product-data').html('<div id="loaderpro" style="" ></div>');
    
    colour = multiple_values('colour');
    brand  = multiple_values('brand');
    size   = multiple_values('size');
    achievements   = multiple_values('achievements');
   
            $.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:'post',
    data:{colour:colour,brand:brand,size:size,achievements:achievements,sprice:$(".price1" ).val(),eprice:$( ".price2" ).val()},
    success:function(result){
     $('.product-data').html(result);
    }
   });
  });
  
 });
 
 
 function multiple_values(inputclass){
  var val = new Array();
  $("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
      val.push($(this).val());
  });
  return val;
 }
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
          <select>
          <option class="item_filter" value="showAll" selected="selected">Show All Products</option>
          <?php
          
          
          $query = "select your_achievements from info_user where user_status = '1'";  
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error());
          
          while($achievementsdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
          {

              ?>
              <option selected="selected" class="item_filter" value="<?php echo $achievementsdata['your_achievements']; ?>"><?php echo $achievementsdata['your_achievements']; ?></option>
              <?php
          }
          ?>
          </select>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `onchange` event like this

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

and your data variable should be like this

```
data:{'colour':colour,'brand':brand,'size':size,'achievements':achievements,'sprice':$(".price1" ).val(),'eprice':$( ".price2" ).val()},
```

make sure your all variable's value are exist.
your ajax code should be like this

```
$(function(){
        $('select').on('change', function() {
            $('.product-data').html('<div id="loaderpro" style="" ></div>');
             colour = multiple_values('colour');
             brand  = multiple_values('brand');
             size   = multiple_values('size');
             achievements   = multiple_values('achievements');
            $.ajax({
                url:"ajax.php",
                type:'post',
                data:{'colour':colour,'brand':brand,'size':size,'achievements':achievements,'sprice':$(".price1" ).val(),'eprice':$( ".price2" ).val()},
                success:function(result){
                    $('.product-data').html(result);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: hey,I did all changes according your suggestion. Now, I am getting alert the selected value. But, how to show that selected value? I mean filter by dropdown ! thanks for code....

Comment: are you getting all variable values like colour = multiple_values('colour');
             brand  = multiple_values('brand');
             size   = multiple_values('size');
             achievements   = multiple_values('achievements');

Comment: let me know your html code i will provide you solution

Comment: brother this is the link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5d86df5bf1d7122d69d3ad8b225ee14b20180409073230/aaa28c6d5930806bc36efafd2cbd757020180409073230/33965e

Comment: please have a look

Comment: i did not find send exact url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168540/discussion-between-stack-and-rahul-shrivastava).